# Git revert several commit from internal github

Tags: git, github

There is a way to revert 4 commits which pushed to github 
to previos commit, for example 
the master is now in

`60cd87e7de2306279f7155d1366f468515a0319g`

and I want to revert it (the master) to

```
70bc987ac1dcaa43af19699859a8a09d8006253w
```

Can I do it from git hub or any other simple way will be very helpful.

I did in the IDE web storm revert like

git reset --hard 70bc987ac1dcaa43af19699859a8a09d8006253w

but not sure how to do this as the new(old) master

Comment: Github is a site (and company). There ain't no such thing as "internal github".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't properly reset your master to an old state without a `force push`.

What you can do is issue this command

```
git log 60cd87e7de2306279f7155d1366f468515a0319g
```

Copy the id of the commits until (but not including) the commit you want to revert do, and revert them by adding negative commit, in the reverse order :

```
git revert commit_A
git revert commit_B
git revert commit_C
git revert commit_D
```

This will create 4 commits.

Then, push them normally with

```
git push origin master
```

---

If nobody else has cloned this repository, you don't care about the history and you really know what you're doing, you can issue a force push

```
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: And are you sure force push is not exactly what is called for in this case? (No, I don't know it _is_. But I don't know it isn't either.)

Comment: How to do a force push ? I own this repo so I can do that

Comment: @JanHudec This is tagged github. github doesn't really like force push. Anyway, force push isn't a good way to teach.

Comment: @JennyM Edited my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks its too risky...What do you mean but push it normally ? I revert 4 commits and then what should I do to make the master to be with the previous 4 commit?

Comment: @JennyM Edited again.

Comment: Thanks I try it and I got error Could not checkout null with start point (some id which I don't see in the git commits I think I try to do it with force but it never merged to the master ) , any idea how to proceed ?